# Jquery mobile autocomplete to a listview

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I like to add autocomplete feature for my jquery mobile page on a text box such that when user enters it should show the results in listview format. The code below shows the results but not in the listview format. Can someone point out how to fix it. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head> 
<title>Finder</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
  input{text-transform:uppercase;} 
</style>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#firstinputbox" ).autocomplete({

source: function( request, response ) {

$.ajax({

url: "http://ziplocator.cloudfoundry.com/rest/startsWithCity/",

dataType: "json",

data: {

maxRows: 10,

startsWith: request.term

},

success: function(data) {

response( $.map( data.zipcodes, function( item ) {
var listItem = ' <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li "><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="/XYC/XDetail/' + item.cityName + '" target="_self" class="ui-link-inherit">' + item.zipcodeId + '</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r"></span></div></li>';
$(listItem).appendTo("#suggestions");

return {

label: item.cityName + ", " +item.zipcodeId + ", " + item.state,

value: item.cityName

}

}));

}

});

},

minLength: 1,

open: function() {

},

close: function() {

$('ul li').remove();
//should attach the value to the text box

}

});


}); 

</script>


</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="inputdialog">
    <div data-role="header">
       <h1>Enter Criteria here</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="text" id="firstinputbox"  placeholder="Enter here"/>
        <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't play well with jQuery Mobile. I read a post about someone implementing their own Autocomplete functionality, might want to give it a read. http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/27/Example-of-Autocomplete-in-jQuery-Mobile

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the listview() function on your content after inserting the new content:

```
$('#suggestions').listview();
```

See [Elijah Manor's explanation](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/dynamically-appending-elements-to.html) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the listview refresh method in your ajax success function.

```
$('#suggestions').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: codaniel I tried that but still not working. So basically I am seeing the listview but also seeing one more unformatted list on top of that. All I am looking for is just the listview but somehow the unformatter list with bullet points is also coming on top of that.

Comment: Are you adding something like this to your code `$('#suggestions').append(listitem).listview('refresh');`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

In `<li>` tag remove class..... `class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li "`

Then it shows results in list view formats